# Are every 2 DFAs with $n$ states for a language $L$ isomorphic to each other?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

Consider 2 DFAs both determining a language $L$. Both DFAs have the same number of states $n$. Can I then conclude that these two DFAs are isomorphic?

I think the answer is yes, because if I'd make an $MN(L)$ relation with $n$ equivalence classes and map it to a $DFA$, there'd only be one result (at least I believe so). Thus both of the DFAs map to the same $MN(L)$ relation.

Is this reasoning correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M$ be a DFA for the language $L$ and let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be $M$ with two different collections of some number $m$ of unreachable states added. $M_1$ and $M_2$ both have the same number of states and both accept $L$, but they need not be isomorphic.

For a less trivial example, consider the following two DFAs:

```
Start state: 1
Accepting states: 2, 4
1 -a-> 2   1 -b-> 1
2 -a-> 3   2 -b-> 2
3 -a-> 4   3 -b-> 3
4 -a-> 1   4 -b-> 4

Start state: 1
Accepting states: 2, 4
1 -a-> 2   1 -b-> 3
2 -a-> 3   2 -b-> 4
3 -a-> 4   3 -b-> 1
4 -a-> 1   4 -b-> 2
```

These two 4-state DFAs are non-isomorphic, but both accept the same language, namely the language of all strings over the alphabet $\{a, b\}$ which have an odd number of $a$s.

Note that if two DFAs accepting the same language have the same number of nodes, and that number is *minimal* among DFAs accepting that language, then the two DFAs must be isomorphic. See [DFA minimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization).

Comment: That makes sense! So what about 2 DFAs with no unreachable states?

Comment: @Bram I have edited my answer with another example.